# How do I test insufficient funds "PayPal Guest Checkout" - Server side REST?

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal

I am implementing Paypal Express Checkout - Server side REST.
When the login frame pops up I choose "Pay with debit or Credit Card" which takes me to "PayPal Guest Checkout" page.

I do not know how to test paying with a debit/credit card that has insufficient funds. I cannot find out how to implement any negative testing for that matter.

I have tested live and I get a "400 Bad Request" if the card has insufficient funds. (The payment setup works just fine if there are funds on the card)